# Why does Box 3 lose its width, height and background as soon as Box 2 is floated?

Tags: css

Why does a Box 3 lose its width, height and background as soon as Box 2 is floated (comment is uncommented)?

```
<style>
  .div1 {
     width: 10em;
     height: 10em;
     background: lightblue;
  }
  .div2 {
     /*float: left;*/
     width: 10em;
     height: 10em;
     background: lightyellow;
  }
  .div3 {
     width: 10em;
     height: 10em;
     background: lightgreen;
  }
</style>


<div class="div1">Box1</div>
<div class="div2">Box2</div>
<div class="div3">Box3</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the float:

```css
  .div1 {
     width: 10em;
     height: 10em;
     background: lightblue;
  }
  .div2 {
     float: left;
     width: 10em;
     height: 10em;
     background: lightyellow;
  }
  .div3 {
     clear: both;/*otherwise div3 would be behind the div2*/
     width: 10em;
     height: 10em;
     background: lightgreen;
  }
```

```html
<div class="div1">Box1</div>
<div class="div2">Box2</div>
<div class="div3">Box3</div>
```

If you want to display all div in inline row then use float for all divs.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see it now. Adding border to div3 reveals it. So, whats happening is that the lightgreen box (Box 3) hides right behind the lightyellow box (Box 2), while the text "Box 3" moves to the next line.